# Реальные достоинства Java

Tags: java

Почему Java получила такое распространение (в частности для преподавания в универтетах США)?

Помимо очевидного (топ-маркетинга и т.п.). Все таки если ее кто то продвигал, значит это делалось для чего то, значит есть какие-то достоинства. Если это делали какие то анонимные гении из MIT и Стенфорда, значит они увидели в этом какую то пользу для себя.

Какие у Java есть реальные достоинства?
Все дело в JVM?

Поддержка ООП вряд ли является отличительным признаком, так как есть в куче других языков, кроме того ООП можно использовать даже на языках без его явной поддержки.

Upd: Я корректно задал вопрос и на него можно дать корректный ответ. Если вы не можете перечислить преимущества и ограничиваетесь общими словами, стоит вспомнить, что "нет" - тоже ответ.

Upd2: Не надо прений, перечислите достоинства и все. Если вы достоинств не видите - не пишите ничего. Прошу обойтись без общих фраз и рассуждений, быть максимально конкретным.

Например:
- кроссплатформенность в результате применения JVM
- безопасность вследствие отсутствия указателей и выполнения в управляемой среде.

Comment: Безопасность и кроссплатформенность.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, а для обучения?

Comment: Преподают то, что нужно бизнесу, а бизнесу нужно то, что он использует.

Comment: Говнокодить на `Java` куда сложней, чем в других языках, хотя тоже возможно

Comment: Farkhod Daniyarov, в каком смысле?

Comment: @Eugene язык изначально проектировался так, чтобы на нём было как можно тяжелее выстрелить себе в ногу. Каждый раздел спецификации написан с учётом часто возникавших в разработке и эксплуатации ошибок. Если C++ создавался для того, чтобы облегчить разработку больших систем, то Java создавалась для облегчения их сопровождения. По этой же причине его и монопарадигменным сделали, кстати.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, что именно облегчает сопровождение?

Comment: @Eugene нереально ни в формате комментария, ни в формате ответа разобраться вам всю спеку построчно. Отсутствие утечек памяти, отсутствие переполнений буферов, отсутствие _неопределённого поведения_, отсутствие безусловных переходов, строгая типизация и т.д. и т.п. страниц эдак на 200 текста. Лучше всего Java удаётся оценить, когда довелось хотя бы лет 5 сопровождать большой проект в большой группе программистов. Совсем хорошо, если до этого был такой же опыт с Сишным проектом.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, честно говоря, мне не понятны слова про отсутствие утечек памяти, ведь простое вольное обращение с конкатенацией строк через + ведет к ней, а Android Studio (написано на java) поглощает память в огромных размерах. Даже придумали сборщик мусора, который вообще не освобождает память, а просто роняет приложении при ее окончании. И конечно, мне все таки хотелось бы услышать о других преимуществах Java.

Comment: @Eugene то, что в Java называется утечками - это детский сад. Надо быть очень криворуким, чтобы намертво зажать ненужную ссылку. Конкатенация строк не ведёт к утечкам памяти, максимум к её использованию в больших объёмах, чем нужно. Android Studio потребляет много памяти потому, что это сложная кроссплатформенная IDE со встроенным эмулятором операционной системы. А Epsilon GC придуман в академических целях, а не для применения в проде.

Comment: @Eugene если кого-то хотите "тиркнуть" к комментариях в SO то в начале нужно ставить `@` иначе уведомления не приходят :)

Comment: @Eugene, это не анонимные гении, это [Bill Joy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB)

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, по факту, не важно, как это называть, если приложение бесконтрольно потребляет память, как никакое другое. То, что оно "когда-нибудь" ее может быть освободит - слабое утешение. В Android Studio эмуляция операционной системы? Что за эмуляция? Я вижу только IDE и компилятор. Эмулятор устройства Android идет отдельно и может в нее не включаться - я, например, его не поставил.

Comment: Все что есть в Java есть в других языках, т.ч. об уникальных преимуществах говорить нет смысла. Приемлемость Java объясняется заведомо субъективным балансом преимуществ и недостатков. Вопрос «почему Java популярна» не относится к программированию и на него нельзя дать объективного ответа. ЯП становятся популярными по разным причинам и техническая «крутость» далеко не на первом месте (см. JavaScript).

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы получить всестороний и полноценный ответ на ваш вопрос, нужно вам же поучаствовать в каком то большом проекте с командой, сначала, например, используя С++ (или другой язык того времени, когда появилась Java), другой проект с использованием Java, и подобных вопросов у вас ее останется. Особенно после лет пяти поддержки такого проекта.

Что качается многих других языков, составляющих Java конкуренцию, как например С#, то здесь стоит учитывать время появления этих языков. Когда появился С# (который так же во всем хорош и даже во многом лучше Java), Java уже имела огромное количество типового кода, специалистов, доверие клиентов, большие проекты для влиятельных корпораций, сообщество и вот это вот все, так что поезд шарпа во многих нишах ушел и перетянуть это "одеяло" на себя теперь практически нереальная задача в некоторых нишах.

Что касается языков "третьего эшелона", как любимый вами Delphi, то у них изначально нет никаких шансов для использования в бизнесе, не тот уровень - чисто прикладное использование. Если у вас есть в этом сомнения, то можете попытаться повторить рекомендацию из начала ответа - поучаствовать с командой в большом проекте для бизнеса, например банковского сектора, затем организовать многолетнюю поддержку - сомнения вас оставят, если конечно вы здравомыслящий человек, а не фанатик такого языка.

В общем, Java была первой из того, что, условно говоря, все ждали от языка программирования и за счет этого получила преимущество, которое использует до сих пор

Так же немаловажна кросплатформенность, Java- код может выполнятся и в чайнике и в космическом корабле без изменений в исходниках (не будем отвлекаться на специфические фреймворки, речь о Java core)

Comment: Слишком много общих слов типа "и подобных вопросов у вас ее останется", "практически нереальная задача в некоторых нишах" и "сомнения вас оставят, если конечно вы здравомыслящий человек". И слишком мало фактов и объективных причин.

Comment: Если Вы относите к языкам "третьего эшелона" все языки, выросшие из первого Pascal - то Вы не правы. Крупнейшие компании не хотят зависеть от одной Java - у них все должно иметь альтернативу. Кроме того, есть специальные требования которые Java не может выполнить - и там применяют другие решения. Придется писать свой ответ.

Comment: @Kromster ответ настолько же общий, насколько общий и вопрос. Писать убедительный доклад с доказательствами о преимуществах Java у меня нет никакого желания, как правильно заметили в комментариях - это будет целая книга, более того оно того не стоит. Если у вас есть желание, то можете сделать это. Объективная причина в в ответе есть - она была первой, что ждали от языка

Comment: @dSH я не отношу все языки, вышедшие из паскаля к "третьему эшелону", более того, не смогу и вспомнить даже несколько из них, конкретно Delphi - да, такой язык, так как имел с ним дело и вполне понимаю его "возможности". Так же ясно, что Java - не панацея от всех бед и многие области "не ее"

Comment: @Kromster зачастую невозможно полностью осознать решения, если не сталкивался с проблемой, которую оно решает - [эффект закрытой двери](https://mkremins.github.io/blog/doors-headaches-intellectual-need/). А для банального перечисления преимуществ языка лучше прочитать "Язык программирования Java" Гослинга. Во времена издания этого учебника ещё приходилось объяснять читателю, почему Java - это круто, поэтому в каждой главе много сравнений и пояснений. Впрочем и они могут ускользнуть от внимания читателя, никогда не ломавшего голову над вопросом _владения_ указателем.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev опустим, что вопрос ТС не соответствует тематике ruSO (и, вероятно, будет скоро закрыт). Как вы считаете, если ТС задал такой вопрос, сталкивался ли он с проблемой, или он все же стоит перед "закрытой дверью"? А то получается, что "Java это слишком круто и очевидно, поэтому мы даже не будем себя утруждать ответом на столь банальный вопрос". Было бы лучше все же спуститься с облаков, и проверить свои знания - может быть реальные достоинства за 15 лет уже совсем не те.

Comment: @Kromster ТС скорее всего молод, не имеет реального опыта, нахватался поверхностных знаний и барахтается в мире идеализированных представлений об отрасли. Я прекрасно помню себя в таком же состоянии, отрезвили только три года в офисе. Что касается крутости Java, она никуда не делась, просто появились новые, местами ещё более крутые языки.

Comment: @Kromster сейчас есть языки намного "круче" Java, нет никаких облаков в ее уникальности, может еще лет через 10 Java и уступит свои позиции. вопрос в том, почему java популярна, ответ в том, что она была условно лучшей **тогда**, а сейчас многие не готовы что то менять, определенные отрасли консервативны

Comment: @pavlofff вопрос ТС сформулирован *"Почему Java получила такое распространение ... Какие у Java есть реальные достоинства?"*. Впрочем это уже спор ни о чем :-)

Comment: @Kromster сегодня ее реальное достоинство в экосистеме, сейчас есть много других языков, ничем не уступающих и даже превосходящих Java, но .. кто раньше встал, того и тапки :)

Comment: @AntonSorokin "круче" scala то же, С#, если из мейнстрима

Comment: Возможно, Java как первый язык и выглядит круто, но мне вот пришлось писать на Яве после шарпа, и первой мыслью было "какое убожество". Первое впечатление оказалось верным - C# это Java здорового человека. Популярность Явы вызвана исключительно эффектом первопроходца, плюс хорошие условия лицензирования. А сравнивать ее с C++ это полная глупость - совершенно разные языки с разными областями применения. С Фортраном еще сравните.

Comment: @freim да, я тоже считаю C# лучше. С С++ же сравнивается только потому, что во времена появления Java она была конкурентом именно плюсам, поэтому и "поднялась", что "совершенно разные языки"

Comment: У вас длинный текст, но в конце вы упоминаете всего лишь одно преимущества. Можно было бы место потратить на перечисление оных.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev , я задаю конкретный вопрос, к чему ошибочные рассуждения о моем возрасте и опыте? Это к делу не относится. Допустим, какой то молодой человек действительно захочет узнать про преимущества - и что в этом плохого? Почему бы их не перечислить?

Comment: Кстати, насчет Дельфи то - крупных многолетних проектов то полно, что там должно останавливать? Обычно это ERP-системы.

Comment: На всякий случай напомню, что Java это искаженный до неузнаваемости клон Оберона, а Visual Studio с C# - клон Дельфи (куда более узнаваемый).

Comment: @Eugene, "_Ява - клон Оберона, а C# - клон Дельфи_"... Я бы сказал, что это мощная заявка на вечер охренительных историй.

Comment: @freim, но это так и есть. Про С# и так все известно (поинтересуйтесь кто был его разработчиком), а по Java - например, почему каждый класс в отдельном файле? Потому что в Обероне, очень грубо говоря, модуль (отдельный файл) играет роль класса. Почему определение функции вместе с ее объявлением? Потому что Вирт так сделал  в Обероне. И так далее.. Заимствовали структуру, исказив синтаксис до неузнаваемости.

Comment: @Eugene почему велосипед это самолет - видите у велика колеса, а у самолета они тоже есть .. инженер, проектировавший самолет, в детстве ездил на велосипеде, просто он исказил велосипед до неузнаваемости. Я плакал от ваших мощных аргументов и лучше вам их не использовать слишком часто, на работу я бы вас не взял, если бы вы такое на собеседовании выдали

Comment: pavlofff, кто раньше сделал, с того и скопировали (если, конечно, знали об этом). Создатель Java Оберон знал, т. к. его фирма прямо купила исходники этой системы, оттуда и заимствовал и виртуальную машину, и модульность и все вплоть до мелочей, прикрыв все это сишным синтаксисом. Если ключевые особенности системы совпадают с другой, которая была раньше нее, есть основания говорить о клонировании. (самолет от велосипеда существенно отличается тем, что умеет летать, а в случае с клонированием Java таких отличий не было).

Comment: pavlofff , вы прямо таки нарисовали картину, как я униженно умоляю вас взять себя на работу. Как будто вам есть что предложить и я уже этого сильно захотел.

Comment: @Eugene если вы хотите, чтобы тот, к кому вы обращаетесь прочитал ваше сообщение, перед ником нужно ставить @, тогда придет уведомление этому нику. Не надо меня ни о чем умолять, выдав подобные "перлы" вас мало кто будет воспринимать всерьез, как специалиста, так понятее

Comment: возможно вам лучше посвятить свою неуемную энергию практическому руслу, сесть и начать писать код, а не теоретизировать по бесполезным вопросам и проводить нелепые сравнения

Comment: @pavlofff , "выдав перлы мало кто будет". Вероятнее всего Вам следует подучить русский язык, раз уж Вы общаетесь на нем, даже если он иностранный для Вас, чтобы не шокировать собеседников такими нелепымии ошибками.

Comment: @pavlofff, предлагаю все же вернуться к обсуждению по теме. Скажем, вы могли бы доказать мою неправоту приведя какое-нибудь качество Java, являющееся его характерной особенностью, и которое не было бы реализовано в Обероне. Кто знает, может профессор Вирт был не прав, когда назвал Java клоном Оберона с испорченным синтаксисом.

Comment: @pavlofff, насчет практической ценности знаний о происхождении языков: это помогает пониманию структуры той же Java. Так что IMHO это небесполезные знания.

Comment: @Eugene если вы о лекции в Нижнегородском универе в 2005, то я там не вижу никаких заявлений о клоне, вы как там все на лекции было и почему он это там сказал знаете или только цитату читали в той же википедии? если бы Вирт имел какие то претензии, он бы не заявлял их где то в России на лекции в устной форме через 10 лет. Да ява имеет влияние многих языков до нее, но ни о каком клонировании с переписыванием синтаксиса речи не идет в принципе, не надо впадать в крайности

Comment: @Eugene О покупке исходников оберона Гослингом где то можно почитать?

Comment: @pavlofff , почитать можно у тех, кто слышал лекцию профессора Вирта в политехническом музее в 2005 году. Это был ответ на вопрос профессору с места о языке Java. Например, https://arvi.livejournal.com/55547.html . Вирт вообще то на пенсии с 1999 года. Вам, наверное, лучше меня известно в каком году началась широкая реклама языка Java. Вы говорите "из многих" - почему бы тогда не перечислить эти "многие"? В каком языке до Java была идеология виртуальной машины и модульности одновременно?

Comment: По вашей ссылке я не увидел никаких упоминаний о покупке исходников оберона Гослингом, было бы вообще странно где то увидеть такое, потому что Oberon имеет лицензию BSD и исходники были общедоступны ..

Comment: @Eugene, imho если хотите понять истоки Java, то рыть надо в сторону [Xerox PARC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_PARC) и [smalltalk](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) (оттуда) а в общем, в отношения людей варившихся в то время в котле с названием [Silicon Valley](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: @pavlofff к тому времени  уже потер свой комментарий, потому что понял, что нельзя сказать, что один язык сильно круче другого. C# и Java - совершенно разные вещи. Scala - имхо ну такое, многим не нравится.

Answer (score 3):

Java отличный язык. Делать очень **большие** и **долгосрочные** проекты на нем намного проще - все таки статическая типизация, сборка мусора, возможность заменить почти любую часть системы не обрушив остальное, большая работа по стандартизации библиотек, платформонезависимость, время на обучение программистов и т.д. Т.е. по сумме характеристик язык не имеет себе равных во-многих сферах. Java - это, так сказать компромисс, между бизнесом, программистами и разработчиками языков. Идеальное решение для систем управления крупными компаниями. В java-мире можно заменить любую часть на альтернативу - и это посильная задача. Это очень ценят крупные компании.  А что требуется бизнесу - передается с той или иной скоростью в учебные заведения.

Но! Есть сферы в крупном бизнесе где доминируют решения на других языках. Возьмем как пример Паскаль. Даже если говорить о крупном бизнесе, есть ниши, где потомки первого Pascal успешно применяются и даже доминируют. Вспомните Ada - его используют крупнейшие компании мира для очень сложных задач реального времени. Там особо даже альтернатив нет из-за высоких требований к безопасности. А еще есть ветка, которую сам Никлаус Вирт разрабатывал - Обероны, Компонентный Паскаль, Модула-2 и т.д. И они все применяются - поэтому странно говорить что они не имеют шансов. Они успешны в своей сфере. Бывают жесткие требования заказчика, когда система не должна иметь под собой другой операционной системы- должна ставится сразу на голое железо. И там языки Никлауса Вирта очень даже ничего - и бизнес это тоже знает и применяет. Бизнес - это не одни банки и учетные системы. Бизнес очень разный и потребности у него разные. Что же касается обучения - наверное Java все же преподается не как первый язык программирования. Детей нужно обучать точно не на Java.

Comment: И в Универах она не как первый преподается. Она идет где то на 4 курсе. Как первый у нас идет ассемблер+Си, не считая Делфи))

Comment: @Anton Sorokin Раньше думал: "Зачем меня учили Паскалю?" -  рынок труда требовал другого . Но прошло время - и поменял на это взгляд. И даже кое-что пилю для себя на Обероне-07. Это немного отдохнуть дает после Java и PLSQL, и по-другому взглянуть на вещи. Начинаешь осознавать что, возможно, IT-отрасль и правда на каком-то этапе не туда свернула. Есть статья Никлаус Вирт - "Долой жирные программы"  - очень рекомендую как "отрезвляющий душ".

Comment: Anton Sorokin , это у нас, а я про "у них" - вузы США.